# Unable to use Branch key as a Manifest Placeholders

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking, branch.io

I'm unable to add the Branch keys as ManifestPlaceholders.

**gradle.properties:**

```
branch_api_key_qa="key_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

**build.gradle**

```
falvour_qa {
    ...
    ...
    manifestPlaceholders = [branchKey : branch_api_key_qa]
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test"
    android:value="${branchKey}" />
```

The above code not making `initSession` callback in my launcher activity.

**But providing the key directly in the manifest is working as expected**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
falvour_qa {
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    branchKey: 'key_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            ]
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand! What's the difference between mine and yours?

Comment: you have to put key directly without making variable.

Comment: Can you lead me to any documentation why I shouldn't do it this way? Because all other keys I have used it in `gradle.properties`, everything works but this one is not! WHY?

Comment: i have already try this but I have not access key from an outside variable that's why I am telling to put key directly.

Comment: i dont have any reference. but i have used like my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey"
        android:value="key_live_**********" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test"
        android:value="key_test_***************" />
```

Comment: This works but why it's not working if I try to implement the above?